# How to mount an NFS server directly inside a container？

Tags: docker

I've tried a lot of things, installing nfs-common inside the docker container, the server side seems to be responsive, and every time I try to link, there is output but the connection fails, and the client prompts permission denied or operation not oermitted

I would like to know how to solve this problem

Comment: I'd [use the `docker run --mount` option to mount the NFS volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-service-which-creates-an-nfs-volume).  You can't usually run mount(8) inside a container at all.

Comment: Why can't I mount an NFS server from a container? Isn't the container itself a system environment? ...

Comment: No, a container is a restricted wrapper around a single process where many system-level operations are prohibited.  Mounting filesystems (any filesystem, not just NFS) isn't allowed since that would provide a path to escape from the container and access the host's filesystem.